# ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after 100000 milliseconds

Tags: apache-spark, akka, apache-spark-sql

I have this problem in my spark application, I use 1.6 spark version, scala 2.10:

```
17/10/23 14:32:15 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000
milliseconds]at
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
at
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
at
scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107) at
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:342)
at
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:197)
at
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:680)
at
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:69)
at
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:68)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
at
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:68)
at
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:678)
at
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
17/10/23 14:32:15 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status:
FAILED, exitCode: 10, (reason: Uncaught exception:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000
milliseconds]) 17/10/23 14:32:15 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking
stop() from shutdown hook 17/10/23 14:32:15 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped
Spark web UI at http://180.21.232.30:43576 17/10/23 14:32:15 INFO
scheduler.DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 27 (show at Linkage.scala:282)
failed in 24.519 s due to Stage cancelled because SparkContext was
shut down 17/10/23 14:32:15 arkListenerJobEnd (18,1508761935656,JobFailed (org.apache.spark.SparkException:Job 18 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down)) 17/10/23 14:32:15 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint:
MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped! 17/10/23 14:32:15 INFO
storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared 17/10/23 14:32:15 INFO
storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped 17/10/23 14:32:15 INFO
storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped 17/10/23
14:32:15 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator:
Shutting down remote daemon.
17/10/23 14:32:15 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook
calledBlockquote
```

I read the articules that this problem and I tried to modify the next parameter without result
--conf spark.yarn.am.waitTime=6000s

--conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout= 6000

--conf spark.network.timeout=600

Best Regars

Comment: you need to provide more details

Comment: what other details would you need?

Comment: Finally I fixed this problem. The problem was that the hadoop.config path was wrong defined I set this variable in my SparkContext. When I deleted this set, the spark appliccation termined success.

Answer (score 25):

Please remove the setMaster(’local’) on the code, because Spark by default uses the YARN cluster manager in EMR.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me to remove this line, which was useful during my debugging on local machine! I think this answer should be accepted.

Comment: Solved the issue for me also, Thanks !

Comment: haha.. I too had the same issue.. the error message is so misleading :D

Answer (score 11):

If you are trying to run your spark job on `yarn client/cluster`. Don't forget to remove `master` configuration from your code `.master("local[n]")`.

For submitting spark job on yarn, you need to pass `--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster/client`.

Having `master`  set as `local` was giving repeated timeout exception.

Comment: I didn't set master to 'local[n]', but I got the same exception.